# How to set default list user task assignee task Alfresco activiti with Java-backed

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti

i'm trying to set users in task assignee to a workflow. here is my code :

```
 List<ActivitiScriptNode> listPersonsScriptNode = new new ArrayList<ActivitiScriptNode>();

 for (AssociationRef association : listePerosnsAssociation) {

 listPersonsScriptNode.add(new ActivitiScriptNode(association.getTargetRef(), serviceRegistry));

                }

        workflowParameters.put(AssignationWorkflowModel.ASPECT_ASSIGNEVALIDATORS,
            (Serializable) listPersonsScriptNode);

        WorkflowPath wfPath = workflowService.startWorkflow(wid, workflowParameters);
```

and my model is :

```
       <type name="wfav:assignationValideurTask">
             <parent>bpm:workflowTask</parent>
            <properties>
             </properties>
         <mandatory-aspects>
            <aspect>wfav:assigneValidators</aspect>
        </mandatory-aspects>
    </type>

        <aspects>
            <aspect name="wfav:assigneValidators">
        <associations>
            <association name="wfav:assigneValidators">
                <source>
                    <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                    <many>false</many>
                </source>
                <target>
                    <class>cm:person</class>
                    <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                    <many>true</many>
                </target>
            </association>

        </associations>
    </aspect>
```

the error is : Couldn't deserialize object in variable 'wfav_assigneValidators'.

Has anyone get this error befor??

Answer (score 0):

i have an isssu, i just change

```
      List<ActivitiScriptNode>
```

with

```
      ActivitiScriptNodeList
```